# Using the given hint to find the integral curves of a vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, vector-fields

I have this problem of determining the integral curve of the vector field $\vec\varphi(x,y,z)=(y,-x,1)$, this problem comes with a hint : show that $z'=\big(-\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) \big)'$.

My understanding is that I can solve the system $$\begin{cases}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=y\\
\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-x\\
\dfrac{dz}{dt}=1
\end{cases}$$
and so the integral curves are $x(t)=c_1\cos t + c_2 \sin t$,  $y(t)=c_1\cos t - c_2 \sin t$ and $z(t)=t+c_3$.

My question is related to the hint, I want to understand how to use the hint to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you mean $y(t)=c_2\cos t - c_1\sin t$